# Preventing 'The data has been changed' error when using Me.Refresh with ODBC linked tables

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba, odbc

In my Access application's data entry form I'm using `Me.Refresh` to show the user the new value of a calculated field based on data they entered in a non-calculated field.  The purpose is to give them the deadline for doing a job next.

This Access app is using linked SQL Server 2012 tables via ODBC.  The calculated field is in the underlying SQL Server table, not part of the Access Record Source query because I want to store the calculated value in the actual data, not just as an interface element.

The calculation is very simple:

```
nextjob = jobdate + 79
```

So I have the field for `jobdate` set to run `Me.Refresh` after update.  All well and good.

The problem is that if the user updates `jobdate`, triggers the refresh by moving to another field, then returns to the `jobdate` field and changes the date they entered Access throws a "The data has been changed by another user" error.

I tested the method using native Access tables and the problem does not occur.  However the data needs to stay on the server, so moving to native tables is not a solution for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possible solutions.

1- If it's always `jobdate + 79`, don't store it at all, use a view that has the calculated field.

2- Use `Me.Requery` instead of `Me.Refresh`. If the form shows multiple records, you must navigate back to the current record, you can use `Me.Bookmark` for that.

3- Move the calculation into the Access frontend - make `nextjob` an ordinary column and set it in the form, so it isn't another user (the server) that updates the data.

Comment: So the 'other user' is actually referring to the linked server?  That makes more sense, I was thinking Access was for some reason deciding that another literal user had done it and thus it was a straight-up error.

Comment: Yes indeed. A technically more correct error message would be "The data has been changed by another process", but it probably wouldn't be better understandable... @ReidMcCamish